How do I make an HP Bar?
I need to make an HP Bar in unity with match of protection into it. I want to make it more immersive for the players.
I've tried this:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HealthManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image healthBar;
    public Image sanityBar;
    public float healthAmount = 100f;
    public float sanityAmount = 100f;
    private Coroutine damageOverTimeCoroutine;

    void Start()
    {
        UpdateHealthBar();
        UpdateSanityBar();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            Debug.Log("damaged");
            TakeDamageSanity(20);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Debug.Log("healed");
            CollectHealing();
        }
    }

    public void TakeDamageSanity(float damageSanity)
    {
        sanityAmount -= damageSanity;
        sanityAmount = Mathf.Clamp(sanityAmount, 0, 100);
        UpdateSanityBar();

        if (sanityAmount == 0 && damageOverTimeCoroutine == null)
        {
            damageOverTimeCoroutine = StartCoroutine(DamageOverTime());
        }
    }

    public void HealSanity(float healingAmountSanity)
    {
        sanityAmount += healingAmountSanity;
        sanityAmount = Mathf.Clamp(sanityAmount, 0, 100);
        UpdateSanityBar();
    }

    public void TakeDamageHP(float damageHP)
    {
        healthAmount -= damageHP;
        healthAmount = Mathf.Clamp(healthAmount, 0, 100);
        UpdateHealthBar();
    }

    public void HealHP(float healingAmountHP)
    {
        healthAmount += healingAmountHP;
        healthAmount = Mathf.Clamp(healthAmount, 0, 100);
        UpdateHealthBar();
    }

    public void CollectHealing()
    {
        if (sanityAmount < 100f)
        {
            sanityAmount = 100f;
            UpdateSanityBar();

            if (damageOverTimeCoroutine != null)
            {
                StopCoroutine(damageOverTimeCoroutine);
                damageOverTimeCoroutine = null;
            }
        }
        else if (healthAmount < 100f)
        {
            HealHP(10f);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator DamageOverTime()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
            TakeDamageHP(1f);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateHealthBar()
    {
        healthBar.fillAmount = healthAmount / 100f;
    }

    private void UpdateSanityBar()
    {
        sanityBar.fillAmount = sanityAmount / 100f;
    }
}

But I want to apply it to ingame enemies and collectibles. I only tested it with my escape and enter key. Please help me. I really need some help. If someone can please answer it?

What does "match of protection into it" mean?

In the future, you should try looking for tutorials and searching previous questions. It should be easy to find many resources about how to create a health bar.
A big mistake in your code is putting the HP into the health bar. The health bar is a type of UI; it should be used only to display the health of an object, not to manage that object's health.
You should have a health component that you put on things with health. For example:
[System.Serializable] public class HealthEvent : UnityEvent<Health> {}

public class Health : MonoBehaviour {
    [Min(1)]
    [SerializeField] private int maxHP = 100;

    [SerializeField] private HealthEvent onHealthChanged = new HealthEvent();
    [SerializeField] private HealthEvent onDeath = new HealthEvent();

    private int currentHP;

    public int HP => currentHP;
    public int MaxHP => maxHP;
    public bool IsAlive => currentHP > 0;
    public bool IsDead => currentHP <= 0;
    public HealthEvent OnHealthChanged => onHealthChanged;
    public HealthEvent OnDeath => onDeath;

    void Awake() {
        currentHP = maxHP;
    }

    public void AddHP(int value) {
        SetHP(currentHP + value);
    }

    public void SubtractHP(int value) {
        SetHP(currentHP - value);
    }

    public void SetHP(int value) {
        int newValue = Mathf.Clamp(value, 0, maxHP);
        if (currentHP != value) {
            currentHP = value;
            onHealthChanged.Invoke(this);
            if (health == 0) onDeath.Invoke(this);
        }
    }
}

Then your healthbar would refer to the Health component, e.g.
public class HealthBar : MonoBehavior {
    [SerializeField] private Health health;
    [SerializeField] private Image healthBar;

    private void Awake() {
        Assert.IsNotNull(health);
        Assert.IsNotNull(healthBar);
    }

    private void OnEnable() {
        Assert.IsNotNull(health);
        health.OnHealthChanged.AddListener(OnHealthChanged);
        OnHealthChanged(health); // Force immediate update
    }

    private void OnDisable() {
        health.OnHealthChanged.RemoveListener(OnHealthChanged);
    }

    private void OnHealthChanged(Health health) {
        healthBar.fillAmount = health.HP / (float)health.MaxHP;
    }
}

This is a simple example; I didn't include the "sanity" value, but you should be easily able to adapt this for sanity as well.
